# Presto: cast array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>> into map<string,array<string>>

Tags: sql, hive, presto

I have a table like

```
name            string                                      
address         string                                      
timezone        string                                      
one_key_value   array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>                    
two_key_value   array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>
```

and want to convert it to

```
name            string                                      
address         string                                      
timezone        string                                      
one_key_value   map<string,array<string>>                       
two_key_value   map<string,array<string>>
```

using presto. There is `lateral view inline` but it doesn't really work in presto. How can I do this?

Comment: What would `map_from_entries(one_key_value)` (https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#map_from_entries) return?

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen I get an error when I use that saying function not registered

Comment: Which Presto version is this? `map_from_entries` was added over a year ago...

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen 0.175

Answer (score 3):

Based on the provided information, you basically need two things:

1. Upgrade to something more recent -- latest from Maven Central / Github, or a Starburst-supported (and free) distribution from https://www.starburstdata.com/starburst-presto-sql/ (disclaimer: I am from Starburst).
   0.175 is really a bit out of date.
2. Use `map_from_entries(one_key_value)` (docs: https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#map_from_entries)

Comment: I don't think an update is possible. Is there a way around without upgrading?

Comment: I would try backporting the code from https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-main/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/operator/scalar/MapFromEntriesFunction.java to your version (start with the oldest commit containing the function, `master`'s version will be harder to backport). You can build Presto from source or add this as a plugin.

Comment: The main issue I have is that map in presto is  map(array(K), array(V)) -> map(K, V) , is there a way to do map(varchar, array(varchar)).

Comment: I don't have 0.175 lying around to test any potential solution to this.

Comment: Cool, do you know how I can split the column into array<string> and array<array<string>>

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested thought, but below expression should help:

```
map( transform(one_key_value, e -> e.key), transform(one_key_value, e -> e.value))
map( transform(two_key_value, e -> e.key), transform(two_key_value, e -> e.value))
```

AS per [Presto 0.175 docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.175/functions/map.html):

> map(array, array) → map Returns a map created using the
>   given key/value arrays.
>
> SELECT map(ARRAY[1,3], ARRAY[2,4]); -- {1 -> 2, 3 -> 4}

We can use [array transform function](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.175/functions/lambda.html#transform) to build the array of keys and values from input field ( `array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>`)

> transform(array, function) → ARRAY Returns an array that
>   applies function to each element of array

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a lot :) Do you have an idea about what needs to be done to get the exact result in hive?

Comment: @JohnConstantine , I am not sure if we  have built-in function in hive to achieve this. Thought it should be possible via custom [hive custom UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-CreatingCustomUDFs).